# Remove labels using WhirlyGlobe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am using the (really cool) WhirlyGlobe (https://code.google.com/p/whirlyglobe/) 3D globe display for iPhone in a new application. I can add labels at certain locations using the code shown below. I want to be able to go back and remove a label I added earlier. The Documentation (http://whirlyglobedocs.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/html/interface_label_layer.html#ac17e1ec72e70eec416cb2cac833f46fa) shows a removeLabel method but I cannot seem to get it to work. I can add but not remove Labels. I tried looping through all subviews but cannot find these SimpleLabel instances. Can someone please help me understand how to remove a label? I haven't had much luck finding many examples. Thank you!

```
// Current position
float lat = [[values objectAtIndex:8] floatValue];
flaot lon = [[values objectAtIndex:9] floatValue];

// Create a SingleLabel at this Lat / Lon pair location                
SingleLabel *interimLabel = [[[SingleLabel alloc] init] autorelease];
interimLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PRN %d",[[values objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
[interimLabel setLoc:GeoCoord::CoordFromDegrees(lon, lat)];
[locationArray addObject:interimLabel];
[allLabels addObject:interimLabel];
```

Comment: Surely in the array allLabels? Or locationArray? Are there any similar posts on their Wiki on the Google Code page?

Comment: Can I see the code where you're adding the labels to the layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a single label or a group of labels to the label layer, you'll get back a SimpleIdentity.  Keep that around somewhere.  Then, when you want to delete the label (or group of labels) from the label layer, you pass back in that SimpleIdentity.

What's going on is this.  WhirlyGlobe batches drawable data like a mofo.  Your SingleLabel objects no longer exist as soon as the Label Layer has crunched them down into as few Drawables and it can get away with.  So to refer to those labels, you have to keep around the unique ID.

Now if you want to delete these labels separately or individually change their appearances, then you've got to add them one by one.  One label to one SimpleIdentity.  Otherwise there's no way to refer to them individually.

For speed, I recommend grouping as many of them together as you can get away with.  If that's just too complex for now, add them one by one and then make a note to come back.  So when you say "Why isn't this running as fast as I'd like" you can then say "Ooooo, right."